# Adding isAuthenticated in Node.js route doesn't protect from non-authenticated access

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I want to add a login feature to this web app https://github.com/squallooo/MT5 and protect the '/' route by adding isAuthenticated using passport.js, but no luck. I even deleted the index route to see what happens, but the index view still shows, thus I think I'm modifying the wrong code? Could anyone give me the tips where I need to modify the code in this case? I want the users to be redirected to the '/login' route when accessing '/' route.

my /config/auth file.

```
module.exports = {
    ensureAuthenticated: function(req, res, next){
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
            return next();
        }
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Please login to view this resource');
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

my index route

```
// Passport, Session
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');

// session config
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

// Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

var { ensureAuthenticated } = require('./config/auth');

// I want to protect the routing by adding 'ensureAuthenticated'
app.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a temporary answer. For some reason, app.get('/', ...) route was not working. When I installed ejs (template engine) and then app.get('/', ...) route is working. I am able to protect this route from non-authenticated users now.